# Rendering views stored in an array in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of views stored in a variable that I want to render. This seems pretty straightforward and simple to me -- however, SwiftUI fails to render it. Does anyone know why this is so?

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var currentSelectedView = 0
    @State private var quote = "Hello 123"
    
    var body: some View { // Failed to produce diagnostic for expression
        let viewArray = [FirstTextView(quote:$quote), SecondTextView(quote:$quote)]
        viewArray[0]
        viewArray[1]
    }
}

struct FirstTextView: View {
    
    @Binding var quote:String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(quote)
    }
}

struct SecondTextView: View {
    
    @Binding var quote:String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(quote)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The content of the array is undetermined. `View` is a protocol, the compiler doesn't know what `viewArray[n]` will return.

Comment: It is not about SwiftUI - re-read about swift types, strict typing rules, etc. Swift book should help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. The problem was the elements of array were different types.

```
    var body: some View {
        let viewArray = [AnyView(FirstTextView(quote:$quote)), AnyView(SecondTextView(quote:$quote))]
        viewArray[0]
        viewArray[1]
    }
```